# Is there any functions to check topic subscription or un-subscription status in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my settings screen, I provide users notifications switchers each topics. So I would like to make sure with the status when I subscribe or unsubscribe to turn-on or turn-off the switchers UI. Actually I found where can I get topics subscribed each users from this URL https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server.

Is there any easier way to check them? (e.g. Get information about app)

[image: e.g. Get information about app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct API available as of the moment to check the subscriptions of a specific user on the Client Side. You'll only be able to check it using the [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server).

However, perhaps you can implement something in your App Server to have the list of subscriptions the user has, and have it reflect in your Client App.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Messaging version 17.0.0 almost adds this functionality. The subscribe methods now return a Task object that will complete when the operation is successful.

However, it doesn't really help with seeing what users are currently subscribed to.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging.html#subscribeToTopic(java.lang.String)